# Drag formula across column not have it change the row number in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I drag a formula across columns but have it change the row number, not the column, in Excel?

My formula is:

```
=IF(AND('Selected Plans'!C5<>"East",'Selected Plans'!C5<>"West"),'Selected Plans'!B5,"")
```

I want to drag it to the next column and have it change to:

```
=IF(AND('Selected Plans'!C6<>"East",'Selected Plans'!C6<>"West"),'Selected Plans'!B6,"")
```

Comment: If you drag it down, (instead of across) it should change the way you want, you can then copy/paste special and transpose the column into a row

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX:

```
=IF(AND(INDEX('Selected Plans'!$C:$C,COLUMN(E:E))<>"East",INDEX('Selected Plans'!$C:$C,COLUMN(E:E))<>"West"),INDEX('Selected Plans'!$B:$B,COLUMN(E:E)),"")
```

currently `COLUMN(E:E)` will equal 5 and return the 5th row in the column to the various parts of the formula.  When it is dragged across it will become `COLUMN(F:F)` and return 6 or the 6th row.